# Нужно вывести наибольшее число из массива, если их несколько равных вывести все

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно вывести наибольшее число из массива, если их несколько равных вывести все

Например из

```
X=[1,2,3,2,3]
Y=[3, 3]
```

или

```
X=[4,5,6]
Y=[6]
```

или

```
X=[1,2,3,3,2,3]
Y=[3, 3,3]
```

Мой код

```
Y=(X.pop(X.index(max(X))),X.pop(X.index(max(X))))
```

Но я видимо не туда пошёл, у меня не получается

Comment: А Вы пытались самостоятельно решить данную задачу? Можно увидеть код, который вы написали во время этой попытки и услышать в чем именно у вас возникла трудность?

Comment: Y=(X.pop(X.index(max(X))),X.pop(X.index(max(X)))) Но я видимо не туда пошёл, у меня не получается

Comment: Максимум нашли - уже хорошо. Теперь переберите элементы массива и возьмите те из них, которые равны этому максимуму. Можете использовать списковое сокращение. Можете обычным `append` в новый массив элементы добавлять.

Comment: Вам нужно вывести числа. Вы делаете pop(), да ещё и два раза. Что делает pop() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**x** - *изначальный список;*

**y** - *список с результатом;*

Список **у** делаем пустым и далее заполняем по условию.
Проходим циклом по первому списку и сравниваем каждый элемент с самым большим числом из списка. Если есть совпадения, то добавляем его в список **у**.

```
x = [10, 20, 11, 20, 5, 6, 1]
y = []

for i in x:
    if max(x) == i:
        y += [i]

print(x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
c = max(x)
return [c] * x.count(c)
```

Находим максимальное число из списка, и возвращаем количество повторений максимального числа умноженное на само число в списке.

Comment: Старайтесь давать чуть более развернутые ответы.

Comment: if даже и не нужен, будет две строчки

Comment: Ответ отредактировал, вы правы

Answer (score 0):

Ладно, раз пишут решения, то вот вам однострочник со *списковым сокращением*:

```
print([i for i in X if i == max(X)])
```

Comment: Это хуже чем `[max(X)] * X.count(max(X))`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Не совсем тот случай. Ваш код квадратичный - `max(X)` вычисляется `len(X)` раз.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Для списка из 5 чисел это очень страшно, да :)  Не, так то вы правы, но для учебных целей можно и так